# OAuth2 REST API .NET Standard class - redirect URL?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I am creating a .NET Standard class that will be fed REST API connection information for publicly available APIs. Given that this is a .NET Class - meant to be used by varying front-ends, and some of those front-ends might not have a "redirect URL" to capture the **access token** that is returned by authorizing with a given public REST API:

1. Is there a way to grab an access token from a public REST API without a redirect URL? (It may be a Windows console application for the front end as an example -not always a web app)
2. Does someone have a sample class? I would have thought that this is a straight forward class usable as a building block but cannot find anything on GitHub that represents the basic OAUTH2 workflow in a simple .NET Standard class.  (I don't mind building my own - seems pretty simple once I get the answer to #1)

I am currently using Postman to experiment, but am now ready to build some .NET code... NOTE: I am not trying to build my own OAUTH server - just connect to public REST APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect url is always required for OAuth2 regardless of the environment. The way this is handled for non-web applications is to use a custom url scheme and trap that, or to trap navigation events performed inside the client side browser window (for desktop/mobile apps) to capture the URL that it's redirecting to and extract the token that way.

Comment: ok thanks.  So, in theory I could just use a localhost address/port, capture that and strip out the access token that is passed in?

Answer (score 0):

RedirectURI is used when you use Authorization Code grant type or Implicit Grant of oAuth2, while the authentication and authorization is done by a 3rd party server(for eg: using google authentication for stackoverflow). If the API you are consuming is using password credential or client credential grant type, normally, redirectURI is not necessary.

It do make sense because once a login screen is shown by a 3rd party website(like google), once the user is authenticated, it should know when the flow should go back.

If you don't have a front-end, it means you have to capture and send the username and password of your end user to send it as a REST call, which might be against security policies.

Also refer : [How does a mobile app authenticate with a backend API if the user signs in through social logins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755762/how-does-a-mobile-app-authenticate-with-a-backend-api-if-the-user-signs-in-throu/51771378#51771378)